# jQuery change of checkbox

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if the change method is the correct to use.  What i want is if the checkbox is clicked(checked) the html of the textarea is var two and if the checkbox is unchecked the html of the textarea is var one.  How do i accomplish this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {


$('.image').change(function() {
var one='type information here';
var two='type url here';

if($('.information').html=='type information here') {
$('.information').html('type url here');
} else {
$('.information').html('type information here');
}

});



});
</script>


<input type="checkbox" class="image"/>
<textarea class="information">type information here</textarea>
```

Comment: You need to use jsfiddle. Make a jsfiddle with your example in it and then I will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.val()` instead of `.html()`. Also, notice that you've forgot the parentheses in your `if`-condition.

```
$(function() {
    $('.image').change(function() {
        var one='type information here';
        var two='type url here';

        if($('.information').val() == one) {
            $('.information').val(two);
        } else {
            $('.information').val(one);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please mark the solution as the answer if it resolved your problem :)

Comment: @GrailsGuy There's a 15 minute timeout before an answer can be accepted.

Comment: My mistake!  Just trying to help :)